# How can I take the values from one column and put them as headers next to it?

Tags: google-sheets

I am making a spreadsheet that checks if people have certain tech skills. I have those skills in one column (separated by commas). I want the spreadsheet to automatically take each skill from this column and place them in columns next to it (each skill is 1 column).

Here's how I want it to look: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KF97e1v2X1dlI-a6Yuw0B-dgp-SaWTF-vk7O0nPrcqU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome! What about `=IFERROR(MATCH("*"&D$1&"*",$C2,0),"")`?

Comment: Headers can be created with `=UNIQUE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,C2:C),", ",1,1),1,0)`